# C# mongoDB wont update array in database

Tags: c#, arrays, mongodb, bson

I want to update array in my mongoDB collection. Posting new document works just fine, but it won't update array. Structure of my document is:

```
 var document = new BsonDocument
        {               
            { "post_title",  model.Title  },
            { "post_text",  model.Text  },
            { "post_author",  model.Author  },
            { "post_picture",  model.Picture  },
            { "post_comments",  new BsonArray()  },
        };
```

And my update function is:

```
[HttpPost]
    [Route("api/PostInfo/{Comment}")]
    public async Task Post(Comment comment)
    {
        try {
            BsonObjectId oldId = new BsonObjectId(new ObjectId(comment.id.ToString()));

            var mongoDbClient = new MongoClient("mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017");
            var mongoDbServer = mongoDbClient.GetDatabase("nmbp");
            var collection = mongoDbServer.GetCollection<PostInfo>("post");

            var filter = Builders<PostInfo>.Filter.Eq(e => e._id, oldId);
            var update = Builders<PostInfo>.Update.Push("post_comments", comment.comment);
            await collection.FindOneAndUpdateAsync(filter, update);
            var test = oldId.GetType();
        }
        catch
        {
        }
    }
```

When debugging, i can see that post controller is triggered, and comment values are correct, but when I take a look in database, value of "post_comments" array is empty. No error is thrown in catch block. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the problem was in this line:

```
var filter = Builders<PostInfo>.Filter.Eq(e => e._id, oldId);
```

The correct one should look like this:

```
var filter = Builders<PostInfo>.Filter.Eq("_id", oldId);
```

Comment: You should also consider using PushAll if you plan to add multiple comments at once in your array http://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/update/pushAll/

Comment: Ty for help, at this point i will use only adding one by one. But i will keep that in mind for the future.